# Capturing a desktop screenshot with javascript

Tags: javascript, screenshot

Is it possible to capture a screenshot of the client's windows desktop using javascript? What about in linux and mac OS?

**Clarification**

This question has **not** been asked or answered, because I'm looking to capture the entire desktop, not just the browser. I would also like to capture 'native' screenshot rather than one that is recreated from some underlying representation (which would be impossible on any OS).

Comment: this question is not a duplicate... he's asking about taking a screenshot of the whole desktop, not just the browser

Answer (score 1):

There is an API called `getDisplayMedia` that lets you capture screen contents as a live MediaStream. It doesnt have a lot of support in browsers though.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API/Using_Screen_Capture

If you just want a screenshot, you should be able to find a way to extract just a frame from the streaming video. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822833/only-one-frame-displayed-webrtc-stream)

Answer (score 0):

Exist a plugin that you can configure the image that you want to take or part of element of your DOM like the `body` or a particular `div`.

Plugin is: **[HTML2CANVAS](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)**

Comment: Hey Al. Thanks for this. But I'm looking for a way to capture the entire desktop, not just the browser. In a windows environment I want some way to trigger the screenshot button event on the client side, or something to that effect.