# client's desktop capture with Node js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

Good morning. I want to be able to take snapshot of desktop of clients of a Node application. The problem is to take snapshot of a windows client or mac, considering that the application is on a linux server. There are solutions for doing that on windows or on mac, but any of these solutions work on linux server. I looked for a manner to do snapshot with node, but I found any node module able to do that.

My problem is like this one [Capturing a desktop screenshot with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17742867/capturing-a-desktop-screenshot-with-javascript) but is was not resolved.

So, do you think I cannot do that? do you know a node module or a angular js module, which can allow to take snapshot of client's desktop no matter their operating system? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to capture the _entire_ desktop, not just what's in the browser?

Comment: In fact, I want to be able to capture the entire desktop, and to capture a part of desktop (with width and height) but now the entire desktop is the most important. I don't want to capture the browser, but the client desktop i.e. the client must be able to send a capture of anything he wants

Comment: You're not going to be able to do this without some sort of plugin in the browser then that the user has installed and is aware of - without such a thing browsers are unable to do this as it would be a security risk.

Comment: for linux client, I use ffmpeg but it don't work on the other os.

Comment: I underdand James Thorpe